# Can $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ be expressed as an inverse limit?

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

We know that given a ring $A$ such that $A/\mathfrak{R}$ is absolutely flat, then $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is Hausdorff (it's an equivalence). So $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ becomes a quasi-compact, Hausdorff and totally disconnected space.

We also know that a topological group which is quasi-compact, Hausdorff and totally disconnected is profinite, so it can be expressed as an inverse limit.

Can we see $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ as an inverse limit too?

Comment: In general, $Spec(A)$ is quasi-compact for the Zariski topology. In exercise 3.11, Atiyah-Macdonald say that: "If these conditions are satisfied [Spec(A) is Hausdorff or equivalently $A/\mathfrak{R}$ is absolutely flat], show that $Spec(A)$ is compact and totally disconnected". My question is the following: "is it possible to express in these conditions, in some way, $Spec(A)$ as an inverse limit?

Comment: @federico Sorry, you're right. I think I fell prey to some of the more counterintuitive properties of the Zariski topology. The example I gave makes the spectrum seem so "wide" that I convinced myself it would be hard to cover.

Comment: I read on commalg wiki that the Spectrum of a direct limit of rings is the inverse limit of the spectra of the elements of the cone. That would make it seem attractive to ask if absolutely flat rings can be expressed as nice direct limits. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a theorem like that... all I know is that absolutely flat rings are *subdirect products* of fields.